# Buttons made with React not dry? How to?

Tags: reactjs

I`m new to React.I created a code for four buttons with hover which are working but i repeated the functions for all of them.
I have written 8 functions for 4 buttons. 
How can i make the code cleaner? Is it ok to go with that?  Thank you.

```js
export default class SelectableOption1 extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state= {
      BtnOne: [],
      BtnTwo: [],
    }
  }
  handleHover() {
    this.setState({
      BtnOne: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)',
        color: '#fff'
      }
    });
  }
  handleHoverOut() {
    this.setState({
      BtnOne: {
        color: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      }
    });
  }
  handleHoverTwo() {
    this.setState({
      BtnTwo: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)',
        color: '#fff'
      }
    });
  }
  handleHoverOutTwo() {
    this.setState({
      BtnTwo: {
        color: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const BtnOne = this.state.BtnOne
    const BtnTwo = this.state.BtnTwo
    return(
      <div className='wrapper-btn'>
        <div className='select-div'>
          <a style={BtnOne} onMouseOver={this.handleHover.bind(this)} 
          onMouseLeave={this.handleHoverOut.bind(this)} href='/'>Btn 1</a>
        </div>
        <div className='select-div'>
          <a style={BtnTwo} onMouseOver={this.handleHoverTwo.bind(this)} 
          onMouseLeave={this.handleHoverOutTwo.bind(this)} 
       href='/'>Btn 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you storing in those `BtnX` state arrays?

Comment: there isn't enough code here to review, and you may consider trying [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: First time here and took me a while to see how to post the code..tx,I had 4 buttons and code was too long and i cut 2 out

Answer (score 1):

So here is how you'd cut down on the repetition

```js
class MyButton extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            isHovering: false
        }
        this.handleOnMouseOver = this.handleOnMouseOver.bind( this );
        this.handleOnMouseLeave = this.handleOnMouseLeave.bind( this );
    }
    handleOnMouseOver() {
        this.setState( { isHovering: true } );
    }
    handleOnMouseLeave() {
        this.setState( { isHovering: false } );
    }
    render() {
        const style = this.state.isHovering
            ? { backgroundColor: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)', color: '#fff' }
            : { color: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)', backgroundColor: '#fff' }

        return <a
            { ...this.props }
            className="MyButton"
            onMouseOver={this.handleOnMouseOver} 
            onMouseLeave={this.handleOnMouseLeave}
            style={ style } />
      }
    }
}

export default class SelectableOption1 extends React.Component {
    render() {   
        return(
      <div className='wrapper-btn'>
        <div className='select-div'>
          <MyButton href='/'>Btn 1</MyButton>
        </div>
        <div className='select-div'>
          <MyButton href='/'>Btn 2</MyButton>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

1. Create a component that has the hover state change logic
2. Use that component in place of the links you were using before.

if all your doing is changing the style of the button when you hover over it then you could use css exclusively with the `:hover` selector and just do

```css
.MyButton {
    color: rgba(27, 209, 255);
    background-color: #fff;
}
.MyButton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(27, 209, 255);
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not always bad to repeat yourself, but here you can create a reusable component for the links (not buttons) you are making.

```js
class Link extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHovered: false
    }
  }
  render() {
    const style = this.state.isHovered
      ? {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)',
        color: '#fff'
      }
      : {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)'
      };
    return (
        <a
          style={style}
          onMouseOver={this.setState.bind(this, { isHovered: true })}
          onMouseLeave={this.setState.bind(this, { isHovered: false })}
          href={this.props.href}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </a>
    );
  }
}

export default class SelectableOption1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="wrapper-btn">
        <div className="select-div">
          <Link href="/">Btn 1</Link>
          <Link href="/">Btn 2</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can move the logic of chaning appearance as the link is hovered into the `Link` component.

---

Note that if you just need to change appearance when the link is hovered, you can achieve this with CSS.

```css
/* CSS for Link */
.my-link {
    backgroundColor: #fff;
    color: rgba(27, 209, 255);
}
.my-link:hover {
    backgroundColor: rgba(27, 209, 255);
    color: #fff;
}
```

Then you can remove a lot of code from the Link component.

```js
// Component for Link
class Link extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <a
          className="my-link"
          href={this.props.href}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </a>
    );
  }
}
```

You would still use the Link component the same way: `<Link href="/">Btn 1</Link>`.

Answer (score -1):

You're already using `.bind(this)` so you could pass in an argument to the handler to identify what state key to modify:

```
<a style={BtnOne} 
   onMouseOver={this.handleHover.bind(this, "BtnOne")}
   onMouseLeave={this.handleHoverOut.bind(this, "BtnOne")}>

handleMouseOut(btn) {
  this.setState({
    [btn]: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)',
      color: '#fff'
    }
  });
}
```

(The `[btn]` syntax is a [computed property key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).)

You could also replace your use of `.bind` with arrow functions:

```
<a style={BtnOne} 
   onMouseOver={e => this.handleHover("BtnOne")}
   onMouseLeave={e => this.handleHoverOut("BtnOne")}>

handleMouseOut = (btn) => {
  this.setState({
    [btn]: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(27, 209, 255)',
      color: '#fff'
    }
  });
}
```

You could also encapsulate the button in a little component that takes a `name` prop of `"BtnOne"` or `"BtnTwo"` and implements the above inside it.